# Angular - Assigning value of an observable to a field of another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to assign the value of an observable to a field of another observable.
This is my code:

```
products$.pipe(tap( products => {
  this.data$ = this.data$.pipe(map(data => {
    data.products = products;
    console.dir(data.products);
    return data;
  }));
}));
```

Comment: Hi ! 

Don't forget you ware not here to do your job, we are here to answer question and help a community with problem where they are stuck. So please could you give us input output what you tried ...

Comment: Thanks for reminding that @Saren. I've shared my update in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `switchMap` & `map` operators, to create a new observable with the required data & products, like the following:

```js
const result$ = this.data$.pipe(
  switchMap((data) =>
    products$.pipe(
      map((products) => {
        data.products = products;
        console.log(data.products);
        return data;
      })
    )
  )
);

// Now you can subscribe to the new `result$` observable, and get the data with products:
result$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data.products));
```

Comment: This solution works but it retrieves the data again every time it works. Any ideas?

...
category.component.ts:170 [{…}]
category.component.ts:170 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
category.component.ts:170 [{…}]
category.component.ts:170 [{…}]
category.component.ts:170 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
category.component.ts:170 [{…}]
category.component.ts:170 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the data like this. You need to create and observer and pass the data to it and subscribe it to get the `data` like this:

```
const testFunction = () => {
return new Observable((observer) => {

 products$.pipe(tap( products => {
    this.data$ = this.data$.pipe(map(data => {
    data.products = products;
    console.dir(data.products);
    observer.next(data);
    observer.complete();
   }));
 }));
})
}
.
.
.
.
// subscribe it to get the data

testFunction.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
});
```